# Set Pointer to Object in Parse

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I keep running into the error when trying to set a pointer to another class object in Parse. What is the correct format to set the pointer from an objectID?

Error:

```
[Error]: invalid type for key RestaurantName, expected *Restaurant, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.1)
```

Code:

```
     var uploadPhoto = PFObject(className:"FoodPhoto")
            uploadPhoto.setObject("lZJJHkFmQl", forKey: "RestaurantName")
            uploadPhoto["PhotoName"] = "title"
            let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)
            uploadPhoto["PhotoUploaded"] = imageFile
            uploadPhoto["Votes"] = 0
            uploadPhoto.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been saved.
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                }
            }
```

Comment: I added the full syntax to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pointer with the

```
PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "your_class_name", objectId: "your_object_id")
```

function, and set that to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object id string and a pointer is a reference to an actual object. That object id represents, or rather uniquely identifies, the object, but you can't diectly create a pointer with it. You need to get the object associated with the id.

If you already have it, great, substitute it where you currently put the string.

If you don't, you need to get it by running a query. Technically you could pass the string object id in a different field and have cloud code query and set the pointer (which would be more efficient than querying from the device if you don't already have the object).